# AS3 addChild(). Stack Overflow error

Tags: actionscript-3, addchild

I'm having problems with addChild() from a class.

I have a *Ball* class:

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
import Achievement;
public class Ball extends Sprite {
    //the image I want to add
    var mc:MovieClip;

    public function Ball() {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED, beginClass);
    }

    private function beginClass(event:Event):void {
        mc = new BallImage();
        addChild(mc);
    }

}
}
```

Where *BallImage* is a movieClip in the library exported for ActionScript.

I add it to the main like this:

```
import Ball;
var littleBall:Ball = new Ball();
addChild(littleBall);
littleBall.x=100;
littleBall.y=100;
```

The image loads just fine, and I can see it on screen. But I get a stack Overflow error. Everything seems to work just fine... So I can't figure out what the problem is.

Edit: If I move the addChild() to the constructor of *Ball*, the error goes away. Still don't know what that means. Why can't I add it just when it loads?

Comment: what is happening in the `BallImage` class?

Comment: Edited (BallImage is a movieclip in the library).

Comment: Please paste the stack overflow message

Comment: * Could you add a log of an error?<br/>
* How many balls (instances of the class `Ball`) do you add on the scene?<br/>
* How many images (instances of the class `BallImage`) do you add on a ball? It is possible that one ball has several images because you don't clear it.<br/>
* How much weight does one image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Event.ADDED` will fire any time the object or any of its children are added to the display list. So it fires once when you add Ball, and then fires recursively every time you add a new BallImage to Ball.

To fix:
Either remove the event listener at the beginning of the beginClass function, or use `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` instead (which you should also probably remove the listener for after it fires).

If you don't specifically need to listen for those events, you could also just call beginClass directly from the constructor and bypass the events altogether.

Comment: Also this thread might be helpful in understanding the difference between ADDED and ADDED_TO_STAGE: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=220154

Comment: That is exactly it, thanks. Also, is the error coming from the fact that I'm overwriting the variable mc?

Comment: No, the error is coming from the fact that the beginClass function is effectively calling itself over and over infinitely until the program crashes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you never clean up your event listener.

```
private function beginClass(event:Event):void {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED, beginClass);  // add this line
    mc = new BallImage();
    addChild(mc);
}
```

When you add the BallImage, it triggers the Event.ADDED event again, so you need to remove the listener before you add anything else.